# Writing a Division Function in Scheme

Tags: math, scheme, racket, r5rs

I'm trying to create a Division function using only subtraction. What I have so far is enough to handle positive numbers. What keeps tricking me up is handling it for negative numbers. I can go ahead and just grab the absolute value of x and y and it works perfectly, but then my answer can never be negative. Anyone here whose had to do something similar before?

```
(define Divide (lambda (a b c)
                    (if (> a 0)
                        (Divide (- a b) b (+ c 1))
                        c
                        )
                    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the product of sign values of **a** and **b** to a variable, then deal with only absolute values of both *a* and *b* while doing the recursion. Output then becomes the product of **c** and the *sign* variable as `(* c sign)`. Consider the following:

```
(define (divide num denom)
  (let div ([n num]
            [d denom]
            [acc 0]
            [sign 1])
    (cond
      [(< n 0)
       (div (- n) d acc (- sign))]
      [(< d 0)
       (div n (- d) acc (- sign))]
      [(< n d)
       (* sign acc)]
      [else
       (div (- n d) d (add1 acc) sign)])))
```

For example,

```
> (divide 10 7)
1
> (divide -10 7)
-1
> (divide -10 -7)
1
> (divide 10 -7)
-1
```

Note that if you use the condition `(if (> a 0) ...` instead of `(if (>= a b) ...`, then you add an extra step in your recursion, which is why using your function, `(Divide 10 7 0)` outputs `2`.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this you often want to define an auxiliary function that the main function calls after massaging the data:

```
(define (Divide a b)
  (define (go a b c)
    (if (> a 0)
      (go (- a b) b (+ c 1))
      c))
  (cond
    [(and (> a 0) (> b 0))
     (go a b 0)]
    [(and (< a 0) (< b 0))
     (go (- a) (- b) 0)]
    [(< a 0)
     (- (go (- a) b 0))]
    [(< b 0)
     (- (go a (- b) 0))]))
```